# Cannot find symbol variable in method

Tags: java, function, object, apache-poi, global

I am learning programming in JAVA.
I created a program to print date and time in MS word successfully but now I want to print strings in my MS word document from different functions. I am only able to print them from main.

Here is how my program is.

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
public class bill
{

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
{

//Blank Document
XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument(); 
//Write the Document in file system
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("createparagraph.docx");

//create Paragraph
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
bill date1=new bill();
String day1=date1.date();
run.setText(day1)
document.write(out);
out.close();
}

public String date()
{
int day, month, year;
int second, minute, hour;
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

  day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

  second = date.get(Calendar.SECOND);
  minute = date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  hour = date.get(Calendar.HOUR);

  String day1= String.valueOf(day);
     String month1= String.valueOf(month);
        String year1= String.valueOf(year);  
            String second1= String.valueOf(second);
                String minute1= String.valueOf(minute);
                    String hour1= String.valueOf(hour);
               run.setText(day1); //here is error *
  return day1;

  }
 }
```

As you can see when I used `run.setText(day1);` in my `date()` function a syntax error ocurred saying:

> cannot find symbol variable run.

I am new and sorry I used wrong english or conventions.
Please just help me print data in MS word using this from different functions.

If you guys post a corrected program then I will really appreciate that.

EDIT
I did this but now nothing is getting printed on ms word

```
 import java.util.*;

 import java.io.*;

 import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
  public class bill
{

 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
 {

 //Blank Document
 XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument(); 
 //Write the Document in file system
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("createparagraph.docx");
 bill date1=new bill();
 String day1=date1.date();
 document.write(out);
 out.close();
 }

 public String date()
 {
  int day, month, year;
  int second, minute, hour;
  GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

  day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

  second = date.get(Calendar.SECOND);
  minute = date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  hour = date.get(Calendar.HOUR);

  String day1= String.valueOf(day);
     String month1= String.valueOf(month);
        String year1= String.valueOf(year);  
            String second1= String.valueOf(second);
                String minute1= String.valueOf(minute);
                    String hour1= String.valueOf(hour);
                    XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument(); 
                    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
                       XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
                run.setText(day1+"/"+month1+"/"+year1+"                    "+second+":"+minute1+":"+hour1);

  return day1;

 }
}
```

Comment: run has to be declared/initialized in the method before it can be used.

Comment: I tried that vishal kamat ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you get the syntax error because your "run" variable is not in the same scope that you are calling it from. Variables in methods can only be used or "seen" by other code within the same set of { }.
So for instance something like this **will not work**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int name = "Sally";
    sayHi();
}
public void sayHi(){
    System.out.println("Hi " + name);
}
```

The sayHi method has no way of knowing what name is. You could pass it as an argument though.

Your second example doesn't work because you aren't doing anything once you get the date. You're immediately writing the document without having added the date to your document first. Furthermore, you're only returning the day, not the whole date.

I've written a quick little program that should do what you've asked:

```
public class Bill {

    public static void writeDate(XWPFDocument document) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy         hh:mm:ss");
        String date = sdf.format(new Date()); 

        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText(date);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        writeDate(document);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("createparagraph.docx");
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

A few things.
I took the liberty of using a Date() object, though what you were doing would work.

By convention we capitalize class names in Java.
i.e.

```
  public class bill {
```

should be

```
  public class Bill {
```

By convention, method names should succinctly describe their purpose. Your method name of date() doesn't say much about what is happening.

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your correction is good but for a better structure of code ( as he's learning Java after all) I'd would go for a `public static void writeDate(XWPFDocument document)`

Comment: @seanimus omg you added a class in return specifier?? that is really new to me.. we can do that? can you explain a little. Also can I declare "run" globally so that every function can use it? 
thanks alot.

Comment: @AlexisDelahaye I understand that you are sending an object.. can you please write how will I call writeDate()?

Comment: @ShachinMatta let's suppose `public static void writeDate(XWPFDocument document)` is written , then you'd call it from your main code like that : `XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();  writeDate(document);` so it's purpose is to write a date into a given Document. By the way in Java it's called method rather than function ( OO languages )

Comment: @AlexisDelahaye thanks alot. I know remember reading about it. I need to  brush up my basic concepts. I have made the program but now I have error in the output. Should I post another question or edit on the same one?

Comment: you can edit your question if you think the problem is not solved (according to your original error which was : cannot find symbol variable run). Now I think you have encountered another problem therefore you need to post a new question, but this time make sure you write an explicit title :) Welcome to SO !

Comment: @AlexisDelahaye I agree with your suggestion concerning the code structure and have added it. 

@SachinMatta You can specify a class as the return type of a method in order to let Java know what _type of object_ the method will return. 
Just consider the line of code `XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();` 
Somewhere in the `XWPFParagraph` object there is a method called `createRun()` that will return an `XWPFRun` object. So its method header would be something like `public XWPFRun createRun()`.
However, following Alexis's advice, we don't really need to return an object, so I removed it.